# How to implement a search algorithm for n objectives simultanesously

Tags: java, python, c++, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I need to implement the following requirment, using a search algorithm(A STAR, BEST FIRST):

n vehicles occupy squares (1, 1) through (n, 1) (i.e., the bottom row) of an n×n grid. The vehicles must be moved to the top row but in reverse order; so the vehicle i that starts in (i, 1) must end up in (n−i+1, n). On each time step, every one of the n vehicles can move one square up, down, left, or right, or stay put; but if a vehicle stays put, one other adjacent vehicle (but not more than one) can hop over it. Two vehicles cannot occupy the same square.

I determined hi formula |n - 1 + i - xi| + |n - yi|
For gi formula:

```
gi = g(i-1), for STAY
gi = g(i-1) + 1, for a simple move 
gi = g(i-1) + 2, for a simple hop
```

But I don't know how to implement an appropriate code for this problem, my attempts generating infinite cycles.

Can you help me with suggestions on whici search algorithm would be most suitable and how I could implement it ?

Code for select the next Vehicle which will move

```
auto comparator = [](const Vehicle& a, const Vehicle& b) {
        return ((a.g() + a.h()) < (b.g() + b.h())) ||
            ((a.g() + a.h()) == (b.g() + b.h()) && a.getIndex() > b.getIndex() );
    }; 
    std::priority_queue<Vehicle, std::vector<Vehicle>, decltype(comparator)> vehicles(comparator);
    
    while (unparked_vehicles.size()) {
        while (unparked_vehicles.size()) {
            vehicles.push(unparked_vehicles[unparked_vehicles.size() - 1]);
            unparked_vehicles.pop_back();
        }

        while (!vehicles.empty()) {
            unparked_vehicles.push_back(vehicles.top());
            unparked_vehicles[unparked_vehicles.size() - 1].makeBestMove(this->grid);
            vehicles.pop();
        }
        
        this->display();
        for (int i = 0; i < unparked_vehicles.size(); i++) {
            if (unparked_vehicles[i].isParked()) {
                parked_vehicles.push_back(unparked_vehicles[i]);
                unparked_vehicles.erase(std::begin(unparked_vehicles) + i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for Selection Best Move:

```
std::pair<int, int> new_coordonates = {state.first, state.second};
    int h = -1;
    
    auto leftMovements = [&]() {
        if (checkPoints(parking, state.first, state.second - 1)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second - 1);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second - 1);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first, state.second - 1)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second - 1);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second - 1);
            }
        }
        else if (checkPoints(parking, state.first, state.second - 2)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second - 2);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second - 2);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first, state.second - 2)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second - 2);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second - 2);
            }
        }
    };
    auto rightMovements = [&]() {
        if (checkPoints(parking, state.first, state.second + 1)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second + 1);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second + 1);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first, state.second + 1)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second + 1);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second + 1);
            }
        }
        else if (checkPoints(parking, state.first, state.second + 2)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second + 2);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second + 2);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first, state.second + 2)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first, state.second + 2);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first, state.second + 2);
            }
        }
    };
    auto upMovements = [&]() {
        if (checkPoints(parking, state.first - 1, state.second)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first - 1, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first - 1, state.second);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first - 1, state.second)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first - 1, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first - 1, state.second);
            }
        }
        else if (checkPoints(parking, state.first - 2, state.second)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first - 2, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first - 2, state.second);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first - 2, state.second)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first - 2, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first - 2, state.second);
            }
        }
    };
    auto downMovements = [&]() {
        if (checkPoints(parking, state.first + 1, state.second)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first + 1, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first + 1, state.second);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first + 1, state.second)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first + 1, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first + 1, state.second);
            }
        }
        else if (checkPoints(parking, state.first + 2, state.second)) {
            if (h == -1) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first + 2, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first + 2, state.second);
            }
            else if (h > getPotentialH(state.first + 2, state.second)) {
                h = getPotentialH(state.first + 2, state.second);
                new_coordonates = std::make_pair(state.first + 2, state.second);
            }
        }
    };
    
    upMovements();
    downMovements();
    leftMovements();
    rightMovements();
        
    if (h != -1) {
        move(parking, new_coordonates.first, new_coordonates.second);
    }
```

Comment: java? python? c++? you need to implement it in 3 languages?

Comment: No, but the language with which I implement this problem it's my choice and I was thinking of one of the 3.

Comment: Without seeing your attempt: Split that what's going to sorted into X piles (the number of physical processors may be a good X). Sort each pile in a different thread. Merge.

Comment: "my attempts generating infinite cycles." It seems you have code that moves. Post your [mre].

Comment: The question seems too broad or missing detail. If you analyze what the cost function actually means for possible solutions you'll see that an optimal solution is trivial to construct: If a vehicle stays, you don't loose anything; If a vehicle hops over another, you don't gain anything compared to moving twice with no vehicle in between, so a trivial optimal solution for n>2 is: Each "turn" only a single vehicle moves. Start by moving one vehicle at a time from start position to target position by only doing up and either left or right moves making sure to start and end with an up move.

Comment: I also uploaded the main code I made

Comment: Your code seems to implement an algorithm that only considers a single vehicle per state but the problem indicates that the state should be the combination of n vehicle positions. Is there any explanation for why? Also when implementing A* there is a potential problem: Not moving at all during a turn does not increase the cost of a solution so for any solution you can insert a turn of no movement in any place and still get a solution with the same cost (could be fixed by adding a constant cost per turn taken that does sum up to less than 1 for at least one optimal solution).

Comment: My idea was to put all vehicles in a priority queue, and at each step is the following process: from non-parked vehicles, choose the one with the minimum "f" and perform the next move, following that the second vehicle repeats the process. , without overlapping the new position of the previous vehicle, etc .... and so, although each car moves individually, it would still be at time k time